# How to keep local storage value on page refresh using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to create a click counter using HTML & JavaScript and I want to retain the value of the number after the page is refreshed.

I understand the fact that I have to use local storage for that and I have managed to store the value and display it after the page is refreshed but when I click on the button again, it starts the count from 0 and I do not know how to solve this issue. I want it to retain the value and continue counting even if the page is refreshed.

HTML Code:

```
   <div>
      <p id="display">0</p>
      <button onclick="increase()">increase</button>
      <button onclick="decrease()">decrease</button>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
let display=document.getElementById("display")
    let count = 0
    
    function increase(){
        count=count+1
        display.textContent=count
        localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count))
        
    }
    display.textContent=localStorage.getItem("count")
    
    
    
    function decrease(){
        count=count-1
        display.textContent=count
    }
```

Comment: assign the initial value of count variable from local storage or default it to 0 if there is no such value

Comment: so i will have to write let count=localStorage.getItem("count") ? I've tried and I doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**when window load get the count value from local storage and  init the count variable after that display that count value**

```
const display = document.getElementById("display");

let count = 0;

window.onload = () => {
  count = localStorage.getItem("count")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count"))
    : 0;
  display.textContent = count;
};

function increase() {
  count = count + 1;
  display.textContent = count;
  localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count));
}

function decrease() {
  count = count - 1;
  display.textContent = count;
  localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let display=document.getElementById("display");
        
// Here was a mistake, you don't need to reset counter each time
let count = localStorage.getItem("count") ?
  +localStorage.getItem("count") : 0;

function increase(){
  count=count+1
  display.textContent=count
  localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count))
}
display.textContent=localStorage.getItem("count")
        
function decrease(){
  count=count-1
  display.textContent=count
}
```

try above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
let display=document.getElementById("display")
let count = Number(localStorage.getItem("count")) // here

function increase(){
    count=count+1
    display.textContent=count
    localStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count))
    
}
display.textContent = count // and here



function decrease(){
    count=count-1
    display.textContent=count
}
```

I updated two lines of your code which is commented.

You have to set `count` variable first with value from `localStorage`.